# reading and extracting data from file using python

Tags: python

I am new to python , and I want to extract the data from this format

```
<seq id> <alignment start> <alignment end> <envelope start> <envelope end> <hmm acc> <hmm name> <type> <hmm start> <hmm end> <hmm length> <bit score> <E-value> <significance> <clan>

**FBpp0143497**      **5    151**      5    157 PF00339.22  **Arrestin_N**        Domain     1   135   149     83.4   **1.1e-23**   1 CL0135   
**FBpp0143497**    **183    323**    183    324 PF02752.15  Arrestin_C        Domain     1   137   138     58.5     **6e-16**   1 CL0135   
FBpp0131987     60    280     51    280 PF00089.19  Trypsin           Domain    14   219   219    127.7   3.7e-37   1 CL0124
```

to this format

```
>FBpp0143497
 5      151        Arrestin_N     1.1e-23

>FBpp0143497
 183    323        Arrestin_C     6e-16
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.  This is not "Write Code For Me.COM"

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem in extracting the data from text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873929/problem-in-extracting-the-data-from-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the file with the 'csv' module, using space as a delimiter.
See the documentation for csv.reader

Answer (score 1):

As this is proteomic data, probably you could find dedicated parsers in the [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) package

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() to separate the items at spaces and then print out the values you want from the returned list.