# problem in extracting the data from text file

Tags: python, string, text-processing

i am new to python , and I want to extract the data from this format

```
FBpp0143497 5 151 5 157 PF00339.22 Arrestin_N Domain 1 135 149 83.4 1.1e-23 1 CL0135
FBpp0143497 183 323 183 324 PF02752.15 Arrestin_C Domain 1 137 138 58.5 6e-16 1 CL0135
FBpp0131987 60 280 51 280 PF00089.19 Trypsin Domain 14 219 219 127.7 3.7e-37 1 CL0124
```

to this format

```
    FBpp0143497

5 151 Arrestin_N 1.1e-23

    FBpp0143497

183 323 Arrestin_C 6e-16
```

I have written code in hope that it works  but it does not work , please help!

```
file = open('/ddfs/user/data/k/ktrip_01/hmm.txt','r')
rec = file.read()   
for line in rec :
         field = line.split("\t")
         print field             
         print field[:]             
         print '>',field[0]             
         print   field[1], field[2],   field[6], field[12]
```

the hmmtext file is

```
FBpp0143497 5    151      5    157 PF00339.22  Arrestin_N        Domain     1   135   149     83.4   1.1e-23   1 CL0135   

FBpp0143497    183    323    183    324 PF02752.15  Arrestin_C        Domain     1   137   138     58.5     6e-16   1 CL0135   


FBpp0131987     60    280     51    280 PF00089.19  Trypsin           Domain    14   219   219    127.7   3.7e-37   1 CL0124
```

Comment: @parijat: you should've edit your original question, not post a new one.

Answer (score 3):

to iterate over a file line-by-line, you should do:

```
with open(fname) as file:
    for line in file:
        fields = line.split('\t')
        print(fields)          # select fields you want to print
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `csv` module to parse your tab-separated fields:

```
import csv
filename='/ddfs/user/data/k/ktrip_01/hmm.txt'

template='''\
> {field[0]}
{field[1]} {field[2]} {field[6]} {field[12]}'''

with open(filename,"r") as f:
    csvobj=csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for field in csvobj:
        if field:
            print(template.format(field=field))
```

yields:

```
> FBpp0143497
5 151 Arrestin_N 1.1e-23 1CL0135
> FBpp0143497
183 323 Arrestin_C 6e-1
> FBpp0131987
60 280 Trypsin 127.7
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
rec = file.read()
```

reads your whole file into `rec`, line breaks and all. You probably want to do this:

```
rec = file.readlines()
```

This is just one way to read lines from a file in Python. It's not always the best way, because this will load *all* the lines of the file into memory. If your input file contains, say, three million lines, it might be better to read and process each line one at a time.

Comment: thanks a lot it works, basically I am very new to the language,

Comment: could you let me the better way to do this , as i am thankful for the better method.. as I have to work with proteome dataset

Comment: @PARIJAT: The other two answers here show two different methods to process the data line by line.